# C++11 Support in Eclipse CDT / Windows / Cygwin

Tags: eclipse, c++11, cygwin

I am used to Java and Eclipse. Now I have to conduct my first project in C++, so I am a newbie.

There is already existing c++ code that uses c++11 elements. I have been trying to get it work under Windows 7 (64 bit) with Eclipse CDT (cygwin compiler) for hours and hours, without success. I have already tried many suggested solutions from this forum (-std=c++11 as compiler flag, various symbols (e.g. **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X**)).

To begin with I would like to make the following code compile and run:

```
cout << std::to_string(42) << endl;
```

Using a fresh C++ Project in Eclipse with the standard settings I get the following error:

```
'to_string' was not declared in this scope
```

Any help is highly appreciated, I am slightly going crazy about this...

Best, 
Tobias

EDIT:
Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string number = to_string(42);
  cout << number << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code with includes and main function.

Comment: @SergeiNikulov, please see the full code in my edited post, thank you.

Comment: Which version of cygwin g++ is used ?

Comment: @Tobias you code is good. Check it on ideaon https://ideone.com/azg2rV so issue only can be with you configuration.